# Writing to the Next Empty Column

Tags: python

I am using openpyxl to write sql query results into an excel file. If I have it write to column B. How can I make sure it starts write in Column B next time I run this script? I tried using a .max_column in my sheet.cell expression but what it does is that it writes in in like column 'E'

```
       A       B      C      D       E

1    Chris
2    5'11
3    215lbs
4    26Yrs
5
6
```

script:

```
def writeToExcel(1_payments_l,2_payments_l,5_payments_l):

    r_1 = 20
    c_1 = 12

    r_2 = 37
    c_2 = 12

    r_5 = 47
    c_5 = 12
    xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook(fn)

    now = datetime.now()
    last_month = now.month - 1 if now.month > 1 else 12
    last_month = "January February March April May June July August September October November " \
                 "December".split()[last_month - 1]


    sheet = xfile['PPC Cost Per Tran.']
    # sheet['L19'].cell = last_month
    sheet.cell(row=19, column=sheet.max_column).value = last_month
    for 1pymt in 1_payments_l:
        sheet.cell(row=r_1, column=sheet.max_column).value = f'{1pymt:,}'
        r_1 += 1
    for 2pymt in 2_payments_l:
        sheet.cell(row=r_2, column=sheet.max_column).value = f'{2pymt:,}'
        r_2 += 1
    for 5pymt in 5_payments_l:
        sheet.cell(row=r_5, column=sheet.max_column).value = f'{5pymt:,}'
        r_5 += 1


    xfile.save(r'C:\Users\12345\Monthly Indicators Dashboard.xlsx')

    return sheet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `max_column` is decided according to the last *active* cell. This sometimes creates "false" results because even if a cell is empty, if it had some format on it, it will appear as active and affect `max_column`.

For example, you might have had some cells with a specific font color on them. Then, maybe the data in those cells was deleted, but even though you can't see it, this cell still has the font color configured and hence the cell exists in the workbook internals and might change the `max_column` value.

To avoid that, you might want to find the first "data-less" cell manually. Something like:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("book.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
for cell in ws[1]:
    if cell.value is None:
        print(cell.col_idx)
        break
```

Comment: that makes a lot of sense to check for an empty value or None value. I tried your suggestion. What can i put in the column parameter in sheet.cell rr do i keep it as .max_column?

Comment: No I guess you can maintain your own `max_col`. Do the above once in the start of your program, and after each column you write advance the `max_col`

Comment: kind of how i have r_1 += 1? if i do something similar with the column variable i would need some starting point to put in columns= ?

Comment: Yeah more or less, when you know you finished with a certain column, advance the "counter" for writing to the next column. I admit that I didn't get into details of your code. I don't see how you run it as variable names can't start with a number...

Comment: this isnt the real variable names...i just changed it last minute because it has company name variables.

Comment: I see... Well I don't quite understand the loops there, it seems that you might write to the same cell a few times... Maybe that's ok, as I said I didn't dive to the details of your code. Just provided a way to find next empty column. If it helped you, feel free to accept my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222674/discussion-between-ben21-and-tomerikoo).